# Solving a bessel equation by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

For a problem solving class I need to find the general solution of ODE $y''+(e^{-2x}-\frac{1}{16})y=0$ in terms of $J_{\nu}$ and $J_{-\nu}$, if possible. $\nu$ represents the Bessel parameter.

A hint is given, namely that a useful substitution would be $e^{-x}=z$; this should lead to the ODE being reduced to a Bessel equation. Substituting this value leads to the ODE $z^2y''+(z^2-\frac{1}{16})y=0$, which has some form of a Bessel equation with $\nu=\frac{1}{4}$, apart from missing a first order derivative $y'$.

*What is the proper way of solving this equation by reduction to a Bessel equation?*
*Can this be done?*

Comment: if you apply the chain rule appropriately, you should find a first derivative...

Comment: @tired could you follow up on that? I don't see how I can substitute a first derivative of y with respect to z if my 'starting-ODE' doesn't contain a first derivative of y with respect to x.

Comment: Consider $d^2_z y[x(z)]=d_z (\partial_z x(z) \partial_x y[x(z)])=\partial^2_z x(z)  \partial_x y[x(z)] +(\partial_z  x(z))^2  \partial^2_x y[x(z)] $.

Comment: @tired managed to figure it out, wrong use of chain rule indeed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letting $t = \mathrm{e}^{-x}$ we have
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} = \frac{dt}{dx}\frac{d}{dt} = -\mathrm{e}^{-x}\frac{d}{dt} = -t\frac{d}{dt}\\
\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} = -t\frac{d}{dt}-t\frac{d}{dt} = t^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-t\frac{d}{dt}
$$

To tidy up this post with an answer (As I see that you already found your way).